# Is there a way of having a GUI for bash scripts?

Tags: python, user-interface, bash

I have some bash scripts, some simple ones to copy, search, write lines to files and so on.

I am an Ubuntu. and I've searched in google, but it seems that everybody is doing that on python.
I could do these on python, but since I am not a python programmer, I just know the basics.
I have no idea of how calling a sh script from a GUI written on python.

If someone has a link or something to say, please drop a line.

regards, 
Mario

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way of having a GUI for bash scripts?

You can try using [Zenity](http://live.gnome.org/Zenity).

> a tool that allows you to display GTK dialog boxes in commandline and shell scripts.

---

> I have no idea of how calling a sh script from a GUI written on python.

You can do this using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Personally I would recommend that you learn Python and call the scripts from Python instead of trying to write the GUI in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

basically, all bash does is start other programs (and do symbolic math on the command line). So no, you're going to have to involve some other program.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what you want. Calling a shell script from python, is like calling any executable from python, using [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system).

In fact there're several 'guis' for bash, namely [zenity](http://www.schnuckelig.eu/blog/using-zenity-interactive-bash-scripts) and [others](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2460).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to display dialog boxes, calendar selection boxes, etc. you might want to take a look at [dialog](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) and [whiptail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail). They are not graphical - they use text mode - but they may be adequate for your needs.